# Rasterio Permission Denied Error When Writing a Raster

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, tiff, rasterio

```
with rasterio.Env():
    profile = raster.profile
    profile.update(
        dtype=rasterio.uint8,
        count=1,
        compress='lzw')
    with rasterio.open(out_file_path, 'w', **profile) as dst:
        dst.write(im.astype(rasterio.uint8), 1)
```

When I try to run the code above, I get the following error:

```
rasterio._err.CPLE_AppDefinedError: Deleting results\testiff_point.tif failed: Permission denied
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this? Is there something wrong with my environment?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am truly sorry if this is a bad question, I tried my best in conveying my problem.

Comment: Does that file already exist? According to [this issue](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/issues/2058), rasterio will refuse to overwrite an existing file.

Comment: Could be a character escaping issue, with the `\t` in the filename being interpreted as a tab character.  But @NickODell is probably right.